# Check if line from a file contains an uppercase letter in Python

Tags: python, char

I am reading a file line by line and let's say I don't care about anything except "if" this line of the file contains an upper case letter. Because if it does I want to use it. I don't want to use the this line of the file if it does not.

Could I use just an if statement for this? or do I have to use a for loop. I already have two nested statements.

My code:

```
with open(var) as config_file: #open file
for line in config_file: #line by line reading of file
    #if "description" and capital letter is contain in line:
        line = line.replace('\n' , '').replace('"' , '').replace(']' , '') #removes all extra characters
        i = "| except " + (line.split("description ", 1)[1]) + " " #split the line and save last index (cust name)
        cus_str+=i #append to string
config_file.close()
```

Comment: can u share a sample from your file ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  The built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function makes this simple:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if any(letter.isupper() for letter in line):
            print(line)
```

Comment: To add on to Patrick's answer, you could also have used `if any(letter in string.ascii_uppercase for letter in line):`, assuming the `string` module has been imported and you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: Thank you so much! follow up question because I have some strange cases. After the substring "description_" of the line, if the next *letter* found after that is uppercase...print this line. How would I do that?

Comment: That's probably easiest to express as a regular expression `re.search(r"description_[A-Z]", line)`

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is probably overkill for this, but it's extremely simple:

```
import re
if re.search('[A-Z]', line):
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open(var) as config_file :
    data = [i.strip() for i in config_file.readlines() if any(j != j.lower() for j in i)]
```

`data` will contain only strings with uppercase characters.

Comment: This does not do what OP asked. They want to know which lines contain an uppercase, not remove them.

Comment: @JoshJ thanks for the correction, missed that part, fixed now.